# My program runs great but my client wants

Tags: python

My program runs great but my client wants me to remove the arguments inside the parentheses of the point function and move the statements that determine each die into point. What is he talking about? Why? What will this accomplish?

Code and output is as follows as is now. Any help or answer would be great. Thanks in advance!

```
import random
import math
MIN = 1
MAX = 6
ROLLS = 5

def main():
    for count in range(ROLLS):
        die_1 = (random.randint(MIN, MAX))
        die_2 = (random.randint(MIN, MAX))
        print()
        print('-----------------------------------------------')
        combined_roll = point(die_1, die_2)
        print('This program simulates two die being rolled five')
        print('times and calculates their total numbers.')
        print('Here are the combined rolls for the dice!')
        print(die_1)
        print(die_2)
        print('The combined roll is:', combined_roll)

def point(die_1, die_2):
    roll_1 = die_1 + die_2

    combined_roll = roll_1 
    return combined_roll
main()

-----------------------------------------------
This program simulates two die being rolled five
times and calculates their total numbers.
Here are the combined rolls for the dice!
4
6
The combined roll is: 10

-----------------------------------------------
This program simulates two die being rolled five
times and calculates their total numbers.
Here are the combined rolls for the dice!
4
5
The combined roll is: 9

-----------------------------------------------
This program simulates two die being rolled five
times and calculates their total numbers.
Here are the combined rolls for the dice!
5
5
The combined roll is: 10

-----------------------------------------------
This program simulates two die being rolled five
times and calculates their total numbers.
Here are the combined rolls for the dice!
2
4
The combined roll is: 6

-----------------------------------------------
This program simulates two die being rolled five
times and calculates their total numbers.
Here are the combined rolls for the dice!
5
1
The combined roll is: 6
```

Comment: This sounds like a question you should ask your client (teacher?).

Comment: Why don't you ask your client what he wants? I'm sure he can offer a much better answer to this question than anyone else in the world.

Comment: For the people that are expert coders, remember this. You once had questions too, so to take away points from me for a valid question shows the character you have, but thanks to the people who still remember their beginnings!

Comment: getting people to do your homework is not acceptable even when you are starting out.

Comment: I agree! I agree completely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> What is he talking about?

```
def main():
    for count in range(ROLLS):
        print()
        print('-----------------------------------------------')
        combined_roll = point()
        print('This program simulates two die being rolled five')
        print('times and calculates their total numbers.')
        print('Here are the combined rolls for the dice!')
        print('The combined roll is:', combined_roll)

def point():
    die_1 = (random.randint(MIN, MAX))
    die_2 = (random.randint(MIN, MAX))
    print(die_1)
    print(die_2)
    roll_1 = die_1 + die_2
    combined_roll = roll_1 
    return combined_roll
```

> Why? What will this accomplish?

It makes `main` simpler at cost of making `point()` little bit more complex.

Although, you can make `point` a lot simpler if you don't need the `print` statements in int.

```
def point():
    return (random.randint(MIN, MAX)) + (random.randint(MIN, MAX))
```

Comment: `main` is still trying to `print` `die_1` and `die_2`, so this will fail currently. You have to remove those print statements or return the values of `die_1` and `die_2` from `point`.

Comment: @dano, Thanks for noticing the error and letting me know. It's fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

your "client"(read teacher) is likely just trying to get you to modularize it ...

```
def do_roll(number_of_dice):
    points = [random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(number_of_dice)]
    for i,p in enumerate(points,1):
        print "Die %d: %d"%(i,p)
    total = sum(points)
    print "TOTAL:",total
    return total

x = do_roll(2)
```

but now if I wanted to roll 3 dice I could just do

```
do_roll(3)
```

or 25 dice

```
do_roll(25)
```

you could take this further and specify the number of sides (think dungeons and dragons and 12 sided die)

```
def do_roll(number_of_dice,number_of_sides=6):
    points = [random.randint(1,number_of_sides) for _ in range(number_of_dice)]
    for i,p in enumerate(points,1):
        print "Die %d: %d"%(i,p)
    total = sum(points)
    print "TOTAL:",total
    return total

do_roll(5,12) #roll 5 12 sided dice
```